# override langchain llm completion call to handle 400 moderated response

Tags: openai-api, langchain, azure-openai, large-language-model

Using `langchain==0.0.198`, `langchainplus-sdk==0.0.8`, `python==3.10`

I am working with openAI, Azure.
Currently, the [moderation endpoint](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/moderation/overview) that was available in the non-Azure openAI is no longer available with Azure openAI, and has been "bundled" with the call to `Completion` as ["content-filtering"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/concepts/content-filter).

I need to handle the content-filtration myself, since I don't want the llm to respond directly to calls that are flagged with moderation type issues.

How can I override langchain, which is essentially making the `Completion` call, such that I can inspect the response for such flagged moderation, and handle it myself?
[The response is a 400, and the "finish_reason" is "content_filter".](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/concepts/content-filter#scenario-details)

Another main reason to override it is the fact that langchain doesn't seem to handle the 400 well, and crashes later on. [This is one git issue I found.](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/issues/4324)

Looking at langchain code, I think I identified the method I would need to override in its [definition](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/8502117f62fc4caa53d504ccc9d4e6a512006e7f/langchain/chains/llm.py#L254C15-L254C23), or where it is called (I am still looking into it)

If there is any other way of doing that, please let me know.

Thank you!